# Logs scrolling applet/app

Tags: indicator, logs

Does there exist some panel or desktop applet or X application to show various logs of my system, as they scroll?
I know I can open multiple terminals and then tail -f all the logfiles I am interested in. But that has to be done either with a special script or manually as well as positioning the terminal windows. Lots of work each time. So I was interested in a more or less complete solution. Rather large panel applets would also be viable with multiple monitors or 4K display. I am using Lubuntu at the moment, but the DE can be any.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [indicator-script-runner](https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335) and create a "script" which tails the relevant log file.  To run the script, select from the indicator menu and a terminal is launched, executing your script.

For each log file you want to tail, create a separate script.